# How to convert 'hash string' to hash?

Tags: perl

I have hash string stored in file, `{"a"=>1,"b"=>2}`, I open the file and store this hash string to `$hash_string`, How can I convert this `$hash_string` to `$hash_string_ref = {"a"=>1,"b"=>2}`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simple answer:

```
$ echo '{"a"=>1,"b"=>2}' > val.pl
$ perl -le 'my $foo = do "val.pl"; print $foo->{a}'
1
```

The better answer: Consider using a better data serialization format, such as [Storable](https://metacpan.org/module/Storable) or [YAML](https://metacpan.org/module/YAML), or even JSON.

Comment: +1 for the serialization advice. But the `do` thing is not the most safe option.

Comment: [`do`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html#do-EXPR "perldoc -f do") in this case, has all of the same security problems of string [`eval`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html "perldoc -f eval").

Answer (score 5):

use [Perl Safe](https://metacpan.org/module/Safe)

The module will run any perl-code (in a sandbox) and return the result. Including decoding e.g. a structure dumped to a file.

code example:

```
use Safe;     
my $compartment = new Safe;
my $unsafe_code = '{"a"=>1,"b"=>2}';
my $result = $compartment->reval($unsafe_code);
print join(', ', %$result);
```

Answer (score 5):

Your data format appears to be "arbitrary Perl expression", which is a pretty awful data format. Why don't you use [JSON](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON%3a%3aXS) or fuller-featured [YAML](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?YAML%3a%3aXS) instead?

```
use JSON::XS qw( encode_json decode_json );

sub save_struct {
   my ($qfn, $data) = @_;
   open(my $fh, '>:raw', $qfn)
      or die("Can't create JSON file \"$qfn\": $!\n");
   print($fh encode_json($data))
      or die("Can't write JSON to file \"$qfn\": $!\n");
   close($fh)
      or die("Can't write JSON to file \"$qfn\": $!\n");
}

sub load_struct {
   my ($qfn) = @_;
   open(my $fh, '>:raw', $qfn)
      or die("Can't create JSON file \"$qfn\": $!\n");
   my $json; { local $/; $json = <$fh>; }
   return decode_json($json);
}

my $data = {"a"=>1,"b"=>2};
save_struct('file.json', $data);

...

my $data = load_struct('file.json');
```

Comment: The  "arbitrary Perl expression" is std dump/dumper for Perl, and if you *know* that the receiver will be Perl as well, this data format is often a good solution. 

But of course, if you may expect other receivers of the data than Perl, decoders for JSON/YAML, or even xml is far more common.

Comment: @FtLie, First of all, it's not DD output. DD wouldn't output that.

Comment: @FtLie, And then there's the claims that a format that's hard to read and has no parser is a good format. DD is meant as a debugging tool, and it's not even particularly good at that.

Comment: @FtLie, btw, the code in your answer doesn't handle DD output.

Comment: I am sorry but you got three wrongs on a row. 1) Data::Dump would produce a result quite close, and the question contains a simplified example (Dumper would include a $VAR= in front). 2) I claimed that Perl is easy to read for Perl, and Perl do parse Perl quite well, not that a Perl data::Dump(er) is good for everything. 3) which error you you get? It works fine for me. Finally, please contribute to answering the question (how to parse a given string). Btw Using Dumper/Safe is the most common serializer in e.g. CGI::Session.

Comment: @FtLie, I didn't say it wasn't close, but it doesn't matter if it's close. And no, `$VAR1=` in front is not the only difference by far. Which is why your method can lose lots of data.

Comment: @FtLie, Who cares if Perl is easy to read or not. Why do you bring that up? It has absolutely nothing to do anything being discussed.

Comment: @FtLie, It's scary that Dumper/Safe is being used, but one module using it doesn't make it the "nost common" by far.

Comment: please try: perl -e "use strict;use Data::Dumper;use Safe;my $a={1=>2,3=>4};my $d=Dumper($a);my $c=new Safe; print Dumper($c->reval($d)), $d;"

Comment: @FtLie, I know it works for that particular data structure. (Well, except for the complete lack of validation on the "parser"'s part.)